# is knowledge base not available in community portal ?

Tags: community, knowledge

You can have the knowledge base on the standard portal without building a widget, is this not available in community?

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge is available to view with all communities licenses. An add on Knowledge license is required to create and edit articles.

Comment: Actually Knowledge is not showing in my community. @greenstork